# Heroku Create - Won't Create

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I'm setting my son's (ancient) machine up so I can start teaching him how to code. I've installed RVM, updated Ruby and Rails. I had a problem installing Heroku Toolbelt but I found an item that said to install it using Homebrew. So I did that and thought I'd be on my way.

However, when I type "heroku create" I get the following message:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/heroku: /usr/local/heroku/ruby/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: Bad CPU type in executable
```

This machine is running Mac OS Snow Leopard 10.6.8. Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.13.

I've tried everything I can think of and haven't been able to find an answer. Has anyone else been able to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Heroku toolbelt using RVM? Sound like a huge mess. Could you update the question with some machine details? (OS version, system Ruby version?)

Comment: Actually that's what we all run at The Starter league in Chicago and it's what Hartl uses in his Rails tutorial. It's not "Non-Standard". The challenge is that this machine can't run anything newer than Snow Leopard.

Comment: What kind of CPU is it?

Comment: CPU is a Intel Core Duo

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're using a 32-bit cpu for the 64-bit CLI.  Recommend installing from the tarball at: http://assets.heroku.com/heroku-client/heroku-client.tgz

Heroku toolbelt automatically installs the CLI, which (I'm guessing) isn't compatible with your Core Duo CPU.  The link above contains a CLI that should work.

Comment: Thanks Fahad. I think that's the problem. I've downloaded the program and decompressed it. However, I'm not a command line expert and don't quite know what to do now. I see an executable in the "bin" directory. How can I execute it? I tried double clicking on it, the terminal window opened and it ran. But, it's still not working. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hey, @ScottS.!  Sorry, I didn't see this.  I'm not totally familiar with OS X as I use Linux but this should work:

Comment: You need to add the extracted directory to your $PATH.  These commands will extract it and show you where it is to add to your $PATH:
`$ tar xzf heroku-client.tgz && echo "Add $PWD/heroku-client to your \$PATH."

Add /Users/Scott/heroku-client to your $PATH.`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above by fahad, you need to download the 32 bit client from http://assets.heroku.com/heroku-client/heroku-client.tgz

Once downloaded, extract the files from the tarball to `/usr/local/heroku/`. If you have already installed the 64 bit version, then you will need to remove those files from the `/usr/local/heroku/` first.